# SwiftUI TextField color issue with background and foreground

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am trying to set background color to my textfield and it seems to be setting fine for padding area around the textfield but not to the actual textfield

```
struct PrimaryTextField: View {
    var initialText: String
    @Binding var key: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(initialText, text: $key)
                .padding()
                .font(.title3)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color("TextFieldBGColor"))
                .cornerRadius(50.0)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.08), radius: 60, x: 0.0, y: 16)
                .accentColor(Color("AccentColor"))
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the coded i used. Below are the images
[Light mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZeH8.png)
[dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxcZD.png)

How to make the white text field to be gray colored textfield (in light mode)?

I tried foreground color to `TextFieldBGColor` but it is changing the color of text in the text field which i dont want to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SwiftUI's `TextField` holds a `TextFieldStyle` property which controls certain aspects of the UI of the `TextField` - this is what is responsible for the border and added background on your `TextView`. Not sure if this is exactly the effect that you're looking for, but you can simply add the modifier `.textFieldStyle` to your `TextField` to remove the added styling, which will remove the `TextField`'s background color. If you want the border that was originally there, you may have to add that back as custom using the `.background` modifier.

```
TextField(initialText, text: $key)
            .textFieldStyle(.plain)      <------ Added here
            .padding()
            .font(.title3)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color("TextFieldBGColor"))
            .cornerRadius(50.0)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.08), radius: 60, x: 0.0, y: 16)
            .accentColor(Color("AccentColor"))
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
```

Read more on the `TextFieldStyle` protocol here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfieldstyle